# Decltype error - doesn't see method declaration

Tags: c++, decltype

I'm trying to use decltype, but I got the same error every time when I was trying compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Polygon {
private:
    double bok; 
    int katy;
public:
    Polygon(int katy,double bok): katy (katy),bok (bok) {};
void scale(double s){ bok*=s;};
    double area () const{
            return (katy*(bok*bok))/(4.0*tan((M_PI/katy)));}};
        
int main(){
    Polygon polygon(7,10.);
    polygon.scale(2.);
    cout<<polygon.area()<<endl;
    
    if(!std::is_same<decltype(scale),void (Polygon*,double)>::value){
        cout<<'p';
    }
}
```

I got a error: "

```
error: ‘scale’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘scalb’?
   28 |     if(!std::is_same<decltype(scale),void (Polygon*,double)>::value){
```

"
What's wrong?

Comment: Typo: `Polygon.scale` ? `scale` is a member function.

Comment: unfortunately that's not it

Comment: Did you meant to get the member function pointer? Then you need to do `&Polygon::scale`

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a pointer to the member function and prefix it with the class scope in order to refer to it:

```cpp
if (!std::is_same<decltype(&Polygon::scale), void(Polygon*, double)>::value) {
    cout<<'p';
}
```

Be advised, however, that member function type is not a plain function pointer, as for each class there is special type defined within the class scope, which follows this pattern: `ReturnType(ClassName::*)(args)`. Thus in your scenario, if you expect `std::is_same` to match the function, you should specify the conditional expression as follows:

```cpp
std::is_same_v<
  decltype(&Polygon::scale),
  void(Polygon::*)(double)
>
```